# Spring Integration Jdbc Backed QueueChannel Delayed Delivery

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Is it possible to achieve delivery delay when using an `QueueChanne` backed by `JdbcChannelMessageStore`? The idea is to implement an exponential retry to a target `Jms` from the `QueueChannel`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several options.

1. Obvious one: use a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` on your JMS service activator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#retry-advice. Although this one does not provide a persistence in between retries.
2. Use a `ReceiveMessageAdvice` with a `DynamicPeriodicTrigger` to modify its `duration` according to the exception and retry state. See `SimpleActiveIdleReceiveMessageAdvice` for inspiration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers
3. Use a Delayer with a `JdbcMessageStore` t delay messages when they have been retried: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#delayer

Comment: Thanks. trying the `Delayer` with `JdbcMessageStore`. Have a related question, is there a way to post back to the same channel via a function, like .channel("function to get channelName from header"?

Comment: See `enrichHeaders(headers -> headers.replyChannel())`.

Comment: Please see my edit for an infinite loop scenario when the underlying DDLs were not available. It wasn't respecting the `errorChannel` as well.

Comment: Why do you show that to us? It clearly states `table or view does not exist`. So, the answer should be obvious: add that table. Since you pointed to the `JdbcChannelMessageStore` I assumed you are already familiar with DDL for Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#initializing-the-database

Comment: Sorry, was worried about an inadvertent scenario it would go for an infinite loop. Was expecting a fail fast in the startup. Shall add the table.

Comment: Well, that's interesting idea: to fail fast if DB is not initialized properly. Please, raise a GH issue: it totally makes sense to be proactive for such a situation and don't wait for data to flow through the application. Thanks for pointing to this out!

Comment: Thanq, GH issue raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/8680

Comment: The moment I add a jdbcMessageStore(), `DelayHandler` stops retrying and from the JDBC logs could see the DELETE being fired already. `DelayHandler` works as expected with in-memory. Am I missing something, please?

Comment: We need to know how you use `DelayHandler`. Technically, you must not rely on retry with its exception, but rather re-send failed message back to the delayer input channel. I suggest to raise a new SO thread with much more info to investigate and have a proper question context.